# Run babel plugin during bundling time or after bundling

Tags: react-native, babeljs, bundling-and-minification

I have a babel plugin that currently runs pre-bundling and then we use react.gradle on Android to create the js bundle. What I am looking to do is run the same babel plugin during the bundling or post bundling, on the js bundle itself.

Is there a way to do that? Thanks!